# MX-запись в разделе DNS-записей

Tags: vps

у меня впс без панели управления имею доступ sftp помогите куда прописать mx запись хочу добавить корпоративну почту от яндекса (в bind прописывал не получается)

Comment: впс сам по себе не имеет никакого отношения к DNS-записям. Если вы ставили какой-то DNS-сервер, значит расскажите и опишите, что как куда и зачем у вас установлено и настроено

Comment: Куда прописать — в то место, которое управляет интересующим вас доменом, и впс тут ни при чём